# Is there a word for an event that someone is most memorable for?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, is there a word for John Wilkes Booth assassinating President Lincoln? That would be most people's only known event of his life - it'd be memorable but is there a noun to represent that kind of event that someone is known for?

Example: JWB's [ ] was assassinating President Lincoln.

Comment: Does "claim to fame" work or is that too positive?

Comment: @alphabet We could coin a new phrase "claim to infamy" for people famous for something negative.

Comment: I didn't want it to have a negative or positive connotation, is there a neutral word? Just for... I guess someone's 'iconic' moment? But again I didn't want it to be an adjective.

Comment: Welcome! Word requests must be accompanied by a sample sentence showing how the word would be used. Please edit to add one. IMO you won't find exactly what you're looking for, but some options that add additional connotations might be useful, like "watershed event," "defining moment," "breakout role," etc.

Comment: Oh okay! Updated, and defining moment is pretty close! I just wish there was a snappy one word choice for it, some translation from Latin or German that would feel like the word 'Bliss' does.

Comment: There are lots of phrases like "time in the spotlight", "moment in the sun", "big day", "contribution to history", as well as the aforementioned "claim to fame". You could also say informally "John Wilkes Booth's thing was assassinating President Lincoln". BTW, it would help if you indicated what this is for - an academic history publication or something very casual and jokey.

Comment: Slightly more modern may be *viral moment*.

Comment: @StuartF "thing" tends to be something they do regularly, not a single occurrence. The Unabomber had a thing, JWB didn't.